# How do I get all the names in these “a” tags that are in one “div” tag for all the div tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is what the html code that I am using is looking like. Right now with my code it will only give me the first name that shows up per line. I am trying to get each each name from each list and out them together. Like so [Lady Gaga, Ariana Grande] and then the next one would be [J Balvin, Dua Lipa, Bad Bunny, Tainy]

```
<div class="field-content"><p><a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/lady-gaga/3611" title="Click to view a local node.">Lady Gaga</a> with <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/ariana-grande/18441" title="Click to view a local node.">Ariana Grande</a></p>
</div></div>, <div class="views-field views-field-field-description"><div class="field-content"><p><a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/j-balvin/243132" title="Click to view a local node.">J Balvin</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/dua-lipa/243376" title="Click to view a local node.">Dua Lipa</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/bad-bunny/243129" title="Click to view a local node.">Bad Bunny</a> &amp; <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/tainy/243564" title="Click to view a local node.">Tainy</a></p>
</div></div>, <div class="views-field views-field-field-description"><div class="field-content"><p><a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/justin-bieber/10220" title="Click to view a local node.">Justin Bieber</a> Featuring <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/quavo/188366" title="Click to view a local node.">Quavo</a></p>
```

This is my current code that is only giving me the first name of each div tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.grammy.com/grammys/awards/winners-nominees/288'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
cat = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "view-grouping-content")


artistlist = []

for i in cat:
    artist= i.find_all('div', class_="views-field views-field-field-description")
    for l in artist:
        if l.a == None:
            artist2 = "-------MANUAL CHANGE-----------"
            artistlist.append(artist2)

        else:
            artist2 = l.a.string
            artistlist.append(artist2)
```

This will only print out the following:
Lady Gaga,
J Balvin,
and so on. I am confused on how one would go about collecting all the text data.

Answer (score 0):

You can select each row and in each row select all `<a>` or `<p>` tags:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.grammy.com/grammys/awards/winners-nominees/288"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for row in soup.select(".view-grouping-content .views-row"):
    # some rows don't contain <a> tags, only <p> tags:
    if not row.a:
        names = [name.get_text(strip=True) for name in row.select("p")]
    else:
        names = [name.get_text(strip=True) for name in row.select("a.freelink")]
    print(names)
```

Prints:

```py
['Lady Gaga', 'Ariana Grande']
['J Balvin', 'Dua Lipa', 'Bad Bunny', 'Tainy']
['Justin Bieber', 'Quavo']
['BTS']
['Taylor Swift', 'Bon Iver']
['Lil Nas X', 'Billy Ray Cyrus']
['Ariana Grande', 'Social House']
['Jonas Brothers']
['Post Malone', 'Swae Lee']
['Shawn Mendes', 'Camila Cabello']
['Lady Gaga', 'Bradley Cooper']
['Christina Aguilera', 'Demi Lovato']
['Backstreet Boys']
['Tony Bennett', 'Diana Krall']
['Maroon 5', 'Cardi B']
['Justin Timberlake', 'Chris Stapleton']
['Zedd', 'Maren Morris', 'Grey']
['Portugal. The Man']
['Luis Fonsi', 'Daddy Yankee', 'Justin Bieber']
['Imagine Dragons']
['Zedd', 'Alessia Cara']
['The Chainsmokers', 'Coldplay']
['Twenty One Pilots']
['The Chainsmokers', 'Halsey']
['Lukas Graham']
['Rihanna', 'Drake']
['Sia', 'Sean Paul']
['Mark Ronson', 'Bruno Mars']
['Florence + The Machine']
['Maroon 5']
['Taylor Swift', 'Kendrick Lamar']
['Wiz Khalifa', 'Charlie Puth']
['A Great Big World', 'Christina Aguilera']
['Iggy Azalea', 'Charli XCX']
['Coldplay']
['Jessie J', 'Ariana Grande', 'Nicki Minaj']
['Katy Perry', 'Juicy J']
['Daft Punk', 'Pharrell Williams', 'Nile Rodgers']
['Pink', 'Nate Ruess']
['Rihanna', 'Mikky Ekko']
['Robin Thicke', 'T.I.', 'Pharrell']
['Justin Timberlake', 'Jay Z']
['Gotye', 'Kimbra']
['Florence & The Machine']
['Fun.', 'Janelle Monáe']
['LMFAO']
['Maroon 5', 'Wiz Khalifa']
['Tony Bennett', 'Amy Winehouse']
['The Black Keys']
['Coldplay']
['Foster The People']
['Maroon 5', 'Christina Aguilera']
```